# Looking for smallish raster of global elevation data

Tags: raster, elevation, global

I'm trying to find elevation data for the whole globe for a simple mapping application and I'm not having any luck.  I really don't want anything fancy, just something like a 4000x2000 raster of elevation values across the globe would be fine.  I plan to colormap and interpolate it myself.  Does anyone know where I might find something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider the Shuttle Radar Topography Mission (SRTM) 30 product, which is a coarse resolution near-global 30-arcsecond DEM. You can download the data at the following FTP site:

http://dds.cr.usgs.gov/srtm/version2_1/SRTM30/

There is also the [GTOPO30](https://lta.cr.usgs.gov/GTOPO30) elevation data set that is commonly used for these applications.

**EDIT**

The GTOPO30 dataset has been replaced by the Global Multi-resolution Terrain Elevation Data 2010 (GMTED2010), available [here](http://topotools.cr.usgs.gov/gmted_viewer/), which uses a combination of available elevation data sources (e.g. SRTM, Canadian elevation data, SPOT) to create a multi-source global dataset. Credit goes to Vince for pointing this out.

Comment: I was hoping for something that was already stitched together into one big raster rather than broken out into tiles if you know of anything like that...

Comment: @gct The SRTM tiles are actually seamless, so mosaicking them is quite simple in any GIS.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a GIS available to stitch them together myself =C

Comment: I assume then, that all you're really looking for is an image of a DEM and not the actual elevation dataset. If that's the case, here is the single image SRTM DEM as an image: http://photojournal.jpl.nasa.gov/jpegMod/PIA03395_modest.jpg

Comment: @gct Also, if you do find you need a GIS, there are plenty of free and open-source GIS available to you like QGIS, SAGA, GRASS, and Whitebox Geospatial Analysis Tools (for which I am a developer).

Comment: @gct And here is a convenient way of getting the entire GTOPO30 dataset as a single image: http://webmap.ornl.gov/wcsdown/wcsdown.jsp?dg_id=10003_1

Comment: I think that GTOPO30 dataset grabber is just what I need, thanks!

Comment: Wonderful, glad I could help.

Comment: GTOPO30 has been superseded by GMTED2010 https://lta.cr.usgs.gov/GMTED2010